# Code-signing fails when using aggregate targets on XCode 6.0/6.1

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, codesign

I use the Jenkins Build Server with the XCode plugin to generate my builds.

After upgrading from XCode 5.1.1 I get an odd error with the aggregate target I use to generate all my apps at once, when I run the targets individually, the ipas get generated with no code signing issues.

However when I run the aggregate target that mainly just runs each target sequentially (I don't parallelize the builds) I get this error:

```
# Checking original app
+ /usr/bin/codesign --verify -vvvv /Users/Shared/JenkinsRoot/workspace/XCodeVersionTest/build/MyMobileApp.app
Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 1 : [/Users/Shared/JenkinsRoot/workspace/XCodeVersionTest/build/MyMobileApp.app: code object is not signed at all
In architecture: x86_64
]
Codesign check fails : /Users/Shared/JenkinsRoot/workspace/XCodeVersionTest/build/MyMobileApp.app: code object is not signed at all
In architecture: x86_64

Done checking the original app
### Embedding 'provisioning/MobileEnterpriseABC2014.mobileprovision'
+ /bin/rm -rf /var/folders/49/9mzjnxjs3fvf8qk6d8fkfsmh0000gn/T/LvDJMwHoHp/Payload/MyMobileApp.app/embedded.mobileprovision
Program /bin/rm returned 0 : []
+ /bin/cp -rp provisioning/MobileEnterpriseABC2014.mobileprovision /var/folders/49/9mzjnxjs3fvf8qk6d8fkfsmh0000gn/T/LvDJMwHoHp/Payload/MyMobileApp.app/embedded.mobileprovision
Program /bin/cp returned 0 : []
+ /usr/bin/codesign -d --entitlements /var/folders/49/9mzjnxjs3fvf8qk6d8fkfsmh0000gn/T/LvDJMwHoHp/entitlements_rawL2sNQDVD /var/folders/49/9mzjnxjs3fvf8qk6d8fkfsmh0000gn/T/LvDJMwHoHp/Payload/MyMobileApp.app
Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 1 : [/var/folders/49/9mzjnxjs3fvf8qk6d8fkfsmh0000gn/T/LvDJMwHoHp/Payload/MyMobileApp.app: code object is not signed at all
]error: Failed to read entitlements from '/var/folders/49/9mzjnxjs3fvf8qk6d8fkfsmh0000gn/T/LvDJMwHoHp/Payload/MyMobileApp.app'
```

My build settings are fairly normal and are the same for all targets and the aggregate target.

[image: xcode settings]

I can't quite tell what the issue is since the individual targets run perfectly fine, has anyone else run into this issue?
This happens in Xcode 6.0.1 and XCode 6.0 but does not happen in Xcode 5.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to this was to set the "SDK" option under the Jenkins XCode plugins build settings to be "iphoneos."

This fixed it since it no longer compiled simulator builds (x86, x86_64) which XCode 6 or Mavericks had trouble codesigning when an Aggregate target was built.

[image: Jenkins Setting]